# How the override the PlaceholderLeftNavBar from a list form to use the master page'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way for the the list forms(NewForm, DispForm, EditForm) to use the master page's PlaceHolderLeftNav content instead of it own? I know on page layouts if the page layouts implements this place holder by using content tag, then the content that exists within the content tags will be displayed, but I was wondering if you override it, without making any kind of modifications to the list forms at all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand. How do you want to change the navigation when Forms opens inside popup, with setting IsDlg query string param to 1, wich means only few content zones.
If you have some custom features - please describe it.

Comment: The list forms opens on the page and not in a dialog. I have a custom left navigation that I want to appear on in every list forms. It has its own header and footer images attached to it.